# What's main objective, duty and purpose of an Imam?

Tags: shiism, imamah, obligation

What's the main purposes, objectives and duties of a Shia [Imam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imamah_%28Shia_Twelver_doctrine%29)?

Do those purposes, objectives and duties get over when he passes away? And is it possible that he not be able to complete all his objectives and pass away?

Comment: tis a nice question, but i assume the reason which made your inquiry without response, is its length. since this consists of several inquiries which could be hard for users to respond all of them. otherwise I reckon it is a profitable question. So, I suggest you (as a mate) to limit it or divide it in two or three separated inquiries. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

How does Satan misguide people? Many people at once...
**Who is there set by Allah to guide people against Satan at once?**

Who is there to guide people for every era and age? Shouldn't there be one who does have that power as well?

The messengers (Hujjats) of Allah have always been there to guide people... ALL people in the world... even though if they aren't physically present in the place you are... but just as Satan can, so can they.

That is why for everything that we want to do we say اعوذ بالله من الشیطان الرجیم... that we want to be pure for everything that we do... and we need Allah's guidance... and it is in Allah's tradition to always constantly have his guidance done by his hujjats... as they are بَابُ ٱللَّهِ ٱلَّذِي مِنْهُ يُؤْتَىٰ, سبب متصل بین الارض و السماء... (From Dua Nudba).
Just don't get me wrong that this is Shirk... no not at all. They have this ability only because Allah has given it to them... they have nothing by their own.
This belief is for all of Allah's messenger... as Allah always needs to have complete guidance for human beings otherwise on the day of judgement people can come and say... you didn't send down any messenger to us...and we weren't told of what is right and what is wrong.

As long as there is a Satan... then humans do need one against him... that is why Allah has sent 124,000 messengers and some more Imams...
And if there wasn't a Satan... still we as human beings would have needed some person to tell us about the heavens and how to achieve جنه ... in the same way that if we want to take a path we need a navigator (There is a similar quote from Imam Ali)

Right now if you bring 1000 people to a gathering... all would their own approach. Is all 1000 approaches correct? Definitely not. We need someone who Allah has chosen and has been granted with absolute correctness, one who is absolutely on the الصراط المستقیم...

---

**Conclusion**

1. We need a guider for everything, especially for the path of heavens which we are far more clueless than we in comparison to a path to a house/location...
2. Satan is out there and there is a great need for someone against him.
3. Its Allah's tradition to send down messengers.
4. We always need a messenger that is absolute correct, since there are a gazillion opinions on each matter and only one is the best.
5. That person has to be brought to us by Allah and only Allah to be clear from impurity and errors... and therefore all this together necessitates the need of an Imam.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to the duty of Shia Imams, it could be so long to illustrate regarding it completely. But briefly speaking, the Prophet (peace be upon him and his family) is bringer of the religion, and the Imams of Shia are its keepers (The keepers of the religion).
On the other hand, according to Shia, Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) gave the scientific legacy of Prophecy to Imam Ali (pbuh) and asked him to state the expression of the Ma'refah and religious Ahkam and do the tafseer of Qur'an; Then he (imam Ali) hand it to the next Imam, … till it reach Imam Mahdi.

They had some other duties such as:

- Expressing and propaganda of the religion
- Keeping the religion alive and removing the religion from the
  deviations.
- And so forth.

With respect to the other part of your inquiry that inquired “Do those purposes, objectives and duties get over when he passes away?”, I should explain that as far as I know, their way could be continued in the lower lever such as Wali-al-Faqih who can continue their objectives and manners as much as they can (in a lower). Besides, their way could be carried out by referring to Marja’al-Taqids and hadiths of them as well.

---

**References:**

- [www.emamat.ir](http://www.emamat.ir/component/k2/item/5744.html)
- [nahidkhirolahi.blogfa.com](http://nahidkhirolahi.blogfa.com/post/254)

Answer (score 0):

What is the main purpose, duty and goal of the Imam?
Imamate is obligatory and its obligation is theological obligation; It means the obligation on God, not the obligation on people. The meaning of this obligation is that it is a requirement of justice, wisdom, existence and other attributes of divine perfection, and since abandoning such an action requires a defect in the realm of God and is therefore impossible, then performing that action is obligatory and necessary. Of course, this obligation is due to the perfect attributes of God, not that anyone makes it obligatory on God. As God has made mercy and guidance obligatory upon Himself.
Khajeh Nasir says in this regard: Appointing Imam is a favor; Because it brings people closer to obedience and keeps them away from sin, and grace is obligatory on God.
Two types of goals for the existence of the Imam are also stated:
The first goal: the same goals and practical benefits. Accordingly, maintaining the social system of Muslims, establishing social justice, fulfilling Islamic rules, especially rules that have a social aspect, the implementation of divine limits are considered as the goals of Imamate.
The second goal: which constitutes the most important goal of Imamate is: quoting, preserving and explaining the Shari'a.

Ref:https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AA#.D8.B6.D8.B1.D9.88.D8.B1.D8.AA_.D9.88.D8.AC.D9.88.D8.AF_.D8.A7.D9.85.D8.A7.D9.85